# Getting an exception while trying to reach value of the "Set-Cookie" key in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, session, setcookie

I want to reach HTTP / SOAP Header of the response (note that, response is an object, not an xml string) coming from wcf service to get value of "Set-Cookie" key on response. I tried to use `HttpResponseMessageProperty` to get header but it throws an exception called ArgumentException.

In an ASP.NET example, `WebRequest` and `WebResponse` is working well but I am trying to write a library in C# with using proxy methods of the wcf service and because of that, I should use the `HttpResponseMessageProperty`.

Waiting your helps. Thanks.

**Edit:**

I attached a screenshot of the exception in below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(Parameters.ClientService.InnerChannel))
        {
            var response = Parameters.ClientService.SearchFlight(Parameters.AuthenticationHeader, Operations.CreateSearchRequest(fsf));

            var messageProperty = (HttpResponseMessageProperty)OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];
            var sessionId = messageProperty.Headers["Set-Cookie"];

            FlightSearchResultDto result = Operations.CreateSearchResult(response, fsf, BaseProvider);

            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to include that statement in a try 'n' catch statement and manage the exception.

Comment: I am doing same but there is something wrong which I could not understand from try-catch and it is really troublesome.